# Non trivial functional dependency... Not certain here

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

Question:
Consider the following relation:

**Order (Product_ID, Product_Name, Customer_ID, Customer_Name, Date,
Item_Price, Amount, Total)**

OBS: If the same customer sends multiple orders on the same day they are combined. Therefore, we only have one order per customer per day.

### Determine all non-trivial functional dependencies of this relation and provide your reasoning.

I do understand what non trivial FD's are. Basically if X -> Y and Y is not a subset of X, then we have an FD. So when it in this questions asks me to write down all of non trivial FD's, i'm uncertain in regards to how many there really are. So i'd like to mention some that i think are non trivial FD's and then i would appreciate some corrections or if someone can add the ones im missing with explanation on why that's a non trivial FD that would be nice too.

product_id -> product_name..
if we know product id we know the product name

product_id -> item_price...
if we know product id we also know item price(?)

product_id -> item_price, product_name...
if we know product id we know both item price and product name..

product_id, item_price -> product_name...
in this one it's unnecessary to have item price, but it's still a non trivial fd i would assume?

Would these be considered valid non trivial FD's?
there seems to be endless (almost) combinations.. do need to mention them all? also is product name a primary key? if it is, what does that mean then?

Comment: Not only going forward, you can still improve this question by clicking [edit].

Comment: What definition of FD are you using? What process (maybe based on the definition of FD) are you following to find FDs that hold? If you don't have such a process, why aren't you finding one first or asking re finding one (rhetorical), and how did you get those FDs? What did you learn researching finding FDs? PS. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect results.

Comment: Have you done all the reading you were supposed to do for this assignment? Because you will almost certainly have been told that the number of non-trivial FDs to be addressed grows quickly with the number of attributes & how to find which ones hold & don't hold in an organized way & that one can give just some of them in an organized way from which others can be inferred and/or never actually enumerated & how to do so. PS Please ask exactly 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question re where you are 1st stuck following a process you give. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Duplicate of [What did I do wrong? (Find FD from table)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42269533/3404097)

Comment: Typo? "Basically if X -> Y and Y is not a subset of X, then we have an FD" should end "then we have a non-trivial FD". PS Why is "basically" there? (Rhetorical.) PS Please read the edit help re block & inline formating for code & quotes & re line breaks. Please use standard punctuation & spelling. Please don't use uncommon abbreviations. [help] [meta] [meta.se]